# FM Radio on HTC One Google Play Edition

Tags: htc, fm-radio

[My HTC](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=specs&id=4635&c=htc_one_nexus_google_play_edition_htc_m7) One has [the capability to tune FM Radio stations](http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_one-5313.php).

And [the Standard Edition comes with an app](http://www.htc.com/sea/support/htc-one/howto/333252.html) for using it.

However, I can't find a way to use the FM Radio on a (non-rooted) Google Play Edition. Any ideas?

Running Android 4.4.2 ... if that matters.

Comment: I don't think you can: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2479412 this suggests it isn't possible, and any search I've tried turns up nothing. Newer phones aren't suporting FM generally, and I think the Google Editions are included. However, the FM HARDWARE appears to be there, look here http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1833777&page=2 there's a free APK for an FM tuner. I cannot vouch for it at all as my HTC One is on Sense and using that one. Best of luck. Edit: Here's another: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2402380

Comment: @RossC Thanks! It's a shame that the vast majority of the suggested apps aren't FM tuners :(

Comment: I understand but the second link has a tuner apk, the other needs root to work. You're in a bit of a bind there. You could build the stock FM from source if you're adventurous. FM is being phased out on phones, for better or worse I'm afraid, so a hack work around is the best I can suggest for now. I'll keep looking!

Comment: @RossC Thanks again! And if you decide to post your comments as an answer I'll upvote it wholeheartedly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll put this altogether here.

Google and some OEMs don't seem to be supporting FM anymore, as evident in the Nexus 4 and 5 not having any FM hardware built in. The Samsung Galaxy S4 also are carrying on this trend. The theory being that there are Internet raido services that can stream thousands of channels. Which doesn't suit everyone. The theory is that it saves space for the hardware and cost in manufacture.  [Android forums discussion on the lack of FM on Nexus 5](http://forums.androidcentral.com/google-nexus-5/345403-no-fm-radio-nexus-5-a.html)

[This XDA thread suggests it isn't possible](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2479412) however there are FM apps out there.

[This is a very lowly reviwed FM app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ca.gc.crc.fmtwoo&hl=en_GB)  on the Play Store that claims to use the tuner.  UPDATE: Does not work on HTC One.

[This XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1833777&page=2) has an attached apk for an FM tuner that MAY work. I have not tested, the usual warnings about unknown sources applies, of course.

[Another XDA FM radio](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2212234)

For rooted devices there is  [one more here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2402380)

The one that is most recommended that I have found is  [Spirit FM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1059296)  which specifically states that No internet connection is required.

Try them out, see what works, and most of all be wary of permissions and apps you are not confident about.

Comment: I've updated my post to state it doesn't work. Sorry about this, I'd normally test this, but I have no GE of the HTC one so I'm in the dark.

Comment: Well, Spirit(2) FM seems the way to go, but as they don't have a free demo and state that they are still debugging I'll wait for a while and see what happens

Answer (score 2):

**Free Option:** [NextRadio](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nextradioapp.nextradio) by Sprint says specifically it is *not* a streaming services, but uses the FM tuner in your phone. It says it is only for a few Sprint phones, but appears to be installable on my Galaxy Nexus and Moto X, so it should be available for your HTC One Play Edition.

About:

> Key Features:
>
> - Tune in to local FM stations on your phone
> - Find radio stations by genre or frequency in the Guide
> - Uses 90% LESS data than streaming music
> - Get 3X BETTER battery life compared to streaming music

**NOTE:** for another possibly free option, see the conversation below.

**Paid Option:** As stated on [Android Central](http://forums.androidcentral.com/htc-one-x/306366-how-put-fm-radio-t-htc-one-x-most-phones.html), the [Spirit FM](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mikersmicros.fm_unlock) app will do the trick on the HTC One Play Edition:

> If you're an average phone user, & don't know what Android "rooting" is, Spirit will likely > not offer you much more than your stock FM app. If your phone does not have a stock FM app, > it is unlikely that Spirit will work on it.
> Spirit is mostly for Android enthusiasts who "root" & "ROM" their phones. But it also works > on many stock, "store bought" phones.
>
> ...
>
> This Works with:
>
> ...
>
> HTC:
>
> One Stock, Google Play Edition & AOSP One X LTE (AT&T)
> LTE / One S
>
> ...

This is a paid option, but has been quoted to work on your device and you can always refund within 15 minutes if it doesn't.

I had a conversation with an HTC Representative and while he said it should be possible, he could not give me any specifics. The conversation is below.

> Wes: Thank you for
> contacting HTC Chat.Hello Jacob.
>
> Yes y ou can but y ou may need to
> download as a third party app.
>
> Jacob: Do you know of any ? The only
> ones i can find are internet radio ones, I'd like to utilize the fm
> tuner hardware
>
> Jacob: Or do you know of a place i can download the app
> from the non-play edition?
>
> Wes: I really am not sure what 3rd party app
> that would be workable.
>
> Wes: Sorry for the inconvenience.
>
> Jacob: Would
> HTC be able to provide the app from the original HTC one?
>
> Wes: That
> would be a pre installed app. There isnt really a link for them.
>
> Jacob:
> I know. That's why I wanted to ask an HTC representative
>
> Wes:
> I am looking into it at the moment.
>
> Wes:
> https://play.google.com/store/search?q=Fm%20Radio

Tell you the truth though, the second is simply [FM Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tunewiki.fmplayer.android) and it looks promising, but states it's only for Motorola devices.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! A few comments: a) You may want to edit your answer replacing "Sprint" by **"Spirit"**. b) Shamefully _NextRadio_ doesn't support the HTC One GPE. c) _Spirit FM Unlocked_ (which as you said doesn't have a free trial option) runs only on rooted phones. d) _FM Player_ doesn't support the HTC One GPE either.

Comment: Thank you for the note about *Spirit* vs. *Sprint*, haha I read too fast! That's been changed :)  And does that mean you've attempted *Spirit FM Unlocked* on your phone? Their description says it may run better on rooted phones (with more features), but that it should work on stock phones with FM support.

Comment: Answer edited to give supporting info from app descrption

Comment: No, I haven't tried _Spirit FM Unlocked_, mainly because they say that they're still debugging it ... and they don't provide a free demo. I don't feel like that. If they want to get profits, they should tidy up their app first :)

Comment: I'd suggest installing it, playing around with it for a few minutes, and then refunding the purchase. Whether or not it actually works, you'll get to see and then you can make your decision from there.

Answer (score 2):

The standard FMRadio is designed specifically for that chipset employed by the HTC One, you *will* have difficulty in finding support for that said chipset hence the Radio FM apps you see on the Play-Store *may* not have the support for it.

**Vital questions**:

- Which HTC One model are you referring to? After consulting [PDADB.net](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=pdacomparer&id=63&c=htc_one_series) there seems to be a few of them?
- What Android version are you referring to?

Do not forget one important matter about the standard FM Radio, more then often, if not likely, it will have supporting libraries found in `/system/lib` and commonly enough, if an attempt to copy the APK of the app and install it elsewhere will fail either due to missing dependencies on the libraries in question or the chipset does not have the kernel support either.

The mileage will vary depending on the above.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. The phone is this one http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=specs&id=4635&c=htc_one_nexus_google_play_edition_htc_m7. Running android 4.4.2 now

Comment: You might be able to glean in on the kernel config script **if present** to determine the chipset employed by the FM Radio... *hint:* `/system/proc/config.gz` under the key `CONFIG_RADIO_ADAPTERS` or similar.

Comment: Well, I can't find the script, but I'm far of a Linux/Android guru

Comment: More than likely, the kernel has that `config.gz` switched off hence cannot be found in `/proc` directory  (it should read as `/proc` **not** `/system/proc` - my bad).

Comment: Yup. I can access `/proc`, but I don't see any `config*` file